# 2d camera shaking back and forth

Tags: xna

I'm trying to create a smooth moving 2d camera but the camera is shaking back and forth 1 pixel.

Player camera rectangle:

```
public Rectangle recCamPosition(Global global)
{
  return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y , 320, 240);
}
```

Camera rectangle:

```
public Rectangle recCamera(Global global)
{
  return new Rectangle((int)_pos.X / global.zoom, (int)_pos.Y / global.zoom, 320, 240);
}
```

The move method:

```
public void physic(Vector2 position, Player player, GameTime time, Global global)
{
  if(player.recCamPosition(global).X!=recCamera(global).X)
  {
    _pos.X+=(player.Position.X-160-recCamera(global).X)/16;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming _pos is Vector):

```
return new Rectangle((int)(_pos.X / global.zoom), (int)(_pos.Y / global.zoom), 320, 240);
```

Because:

```
(int)0.5f / 1 == 0 / 1 == 0
1 / 2 == 0
(float)1 / 2 == 0.5f
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the Vector2.Lerp() method. It basically interpolates two Vector2 values, and it's great for camera movement. What you've got is fine - but this might just be a bit better. To use it you could simply have the position and size of the camera rectangle as two Vector2s and lerp them. Here's an example.

```
Vector2 CurrentPosition;
Vector2 CurrentSize;

//Speed should be a value from 0.0f to 1.0f
public Rectangle UpdateCamera(Vector2 TargetPosition, Vector2 TargetSize, float Speed)
{
    CurrentPosition = Vector2.Lerp(CurrentPosition, TargetPosition, Speed);
    CurrentSize = Vector2.Lerp(CurrentSize, TargetSize, Speed);
    return new Rectangle((int)(CurrentPosition.X), (int)(CurrentPosition.Y), (int)(CurrentSize.X), (int)(CurrentSize.Y));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i fix the shake but i need to use ints and dont shake for pixel per pixel movement

The solution of this was here`Matrix.CreateTranslation((int)-_pos.X,(int)-_pos.Y, 0)*`
and change by this

```
   Matrix.CreateTranslation(-_pos.X,-_pos.Y, 0)*
```