# MonoGame Point filtering movement appears Choppy/Jerky

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

When you move a sprite that is drawn using point filtering with a decimal number, example : 0.1 pixel or 100 * deltaTime (1.6) the movement appear choppy/jerky because it jumps from pixel to pixel. How would I go about doing to make the movement smooth?

> please don't answer : linear filtering because I get some issues with my map then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. Pixel is smallest part of image. You cannot divide it more. If you don't want smooth image then humble with it. :|

**BUT!**

Problem also can be in how you calculate draw positions. See first answer on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93861/2d-camera-shaking-back-and-forth). It can helps you. If not please post code of your Draw method.

Comment: "how you calculate draw positions" : isn't `float` converted to `int` in draw time anyway ? I haven't noticed any difference when I draw using `float` (vector2) or `int` (retangle or point)

Comment: @Shiro there is something called subpixel movement that instead of jumping from pixel to pixel it blends smoothly between them. By moving the colors instead of the img itself

Comment: @VinnieH01 There is a difference between `subpixel movement` and `smooth subpixel movement`. There is an answer on this relevant question about ways to make the movement smoother  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87353/how-do-you-move-a-sprite-in-sub-pixel-increments. Two interesting techniques are anti-aliasing (basically blurring pixels) and animated sprites (http://i.stack.imgur.com/QZakB.gif) . "Moving the colors" as you describe doesn't really solve the problem. `Blurring the colors on certain pixels` though, can fake the movement into looking smoother.

Comment: @VinnieH01 Using `float` seems to simply be rounded to the closest `int`. If you draw something on `(0.51f,0)` and `(1.49f,0)` it is drawn at exactly the same position which is `(1,0)`. The only benefit from this, is for precision on physics simulations.